# Manage combobox and complex objects

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to figure out how to handle Combobox with complex objects.

I have the following 2 classes:

BackupVersion.cs

```
public class BackupVersion
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public BackupVersion() { }

    public BackupVersion(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

SubsystemVersions.cs

```
public class SubsystemVersions : ObservableCollection<BackupVersion>
{
    public SubsystemVersions()
    {
        Add(new BackupVersion("amit"));
        Add(new BackupVersion("aaa"));
        Add(new BackupVersion("ofir"));
    }

}
```

I also have to following XAML window:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:SubsystemVersions x:Key="Backups"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ComboBox Name="c1"
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Backups}"
                  Text="mmm"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                  IsEditable="true"
                  IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This way, in the code behind, I can get the selected string in the combobox using:

```
this.c1.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

My question is, how can I get back the original object i.e. the BackupVersion object?

Please also comment on the coding style, if I am doing something which is not common (for example, is that the best way to define and bind the collection?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get back the original object :

```
this.c1.SelectedItem;
```